# Monkey patching 'datetime' produces strange results

Tags: python, datetime, monkeypatching, python-datetime

I'm trying to make one of my libraries compatible with Python 2.6. It uses the method `datetime.timedelta.total_seconds` which was added in 2.7, so to make it work with 2.6, I wanted to monkey patch it into `timedelta` like this:

```
import datetime

if not hasattr(datetime.timedelta, 'total_seconds'):

    class timedelta(datetime.timedelta):
        def total_seconds(self):
            return self.days * 86400.0 + self.seconds + self.microseconds * 1e-6

    datetime.timedelta = timedelta
```

This does actually work in some cases, e.g. if I create a `timedelta` variable, it does have this method. But if a new `timedelta` object is produced by subtracting two `datetime.datetime` values, the method is missing from the resulting object.

What's going wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `datetime` module is written entirely in C.

This includes the function that subtracts one `datetime.datetime` object from another. That function -- called `new_delta()` -- directly instantiates `PyDateTime_DeltaType`, which is the original `datetime.timedelta` class (written in C). It won't notice that you've rebound `datetime.timedelta` to your own class in Python-land.

I don't see any easy workarounds.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But to come back to the original purpose, is there a way to make code that uses `total_seconds` backwards-compatible with Python 2.6?

Comment: You could create your own timedelta class that has the same interface and just wraps Python's timedelta while adding your own total_seconds method/property. Just have it take a Python timedelta in the constructor. It's of course an extra step because you have to wrap your timedetlas with your new class.

Comment: @elpres: Do you have the option of refactoring the code that uses `total_seconds` to use something else (i.e. call a wrapper function instead)?

Comment: @aix: Yes, refactoring is a possibility, but backwards-compatibility with 2.6 is not really necessary, just something I thought would be nice to have. I'll have to decide whether the overhead from a wrapper is really worth it. Anyway, thanks for clearing up the situation.